# ASP.NET MVC action methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you RedirectToAction using POST instead of GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129335/how-do-you-redirecttoaction-using-post-instead-of-get)

I have two versions of Index action in my controller, one for GET and another for POST. How can I use RedirectToAction method so that POST version of Index action is called? Normal RedirectToAction("Index") calls the GET version.

Answer (score 1):

[How do you redirect to a page using the POST verb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129335/how-do-you-redirecttoaction-using-post-instead-of-get)