# How to call one Action method from another Action method(both are in the same Controller) in MVC C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Hi From the calling Action Method, I have:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SubmitForms(Note note, string action = "Submit") 
{
     //some code
     RedirectToAction("SaveDemographicForm", "PatientForms", new { model.DemographicFormData,  action="Submit" , submitAll = true });
     //some code
}
```

And this the Action Method that I am trying to call:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveDemographicForm(DemographicForm demographicForm, string action = "Save", bool submitAll = false )
{
      //Some code
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you get an exception message?

Comment: [duplicate of http post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129335/how-do-you-redirect-to-a-page-using-the-post-verb)

Comment: Please add a description of the error you receive or the expected and actual behavior of the application.

Comment: You have to return RedirectToAction not just call RedirectToAction.

Comment: I am not getting any error, its just not hitting the destination Action Method.  I guess it going in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 11):

If they are both in the same controller you don't need to redirect to action, just call it directly.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SubmitForms(Note note, string action = "Submit") 
{
     //some code
     return SaveDemographicForm(new DemographicForm { /*your properties*/ }, "Save", false);
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveDemographicForm(DemographicForm demographicForm, string action = "Save", bool submitAll = false )
{
      //return some json object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call with no return

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SubmitForms(Note note, string action = "Submit") 
{
     SaveDemographicForm(new DemographicForm { /*your properties*/ }, "Save", false);

     //somecode
     //submitforms return
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveDemographicForm(DemographicForm demographicForm, string action = "Save", bool submitAll = false )
{
      //return some json object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `RedirectToAction()` returns a `RedirectToRouteResult`:

```
public ActionResult AnotherAction(int id)
{
    //Do something with the id ...
    return View()
}


public RedirectToRouteResult DoAndRedirect()
{            
    //Do something and go to the desired view:
    return RedirectToAction("AnotherAction", new { id = x.ID });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- using System.Web.Mvc;
- using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

  ```
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
      HtmlHelper helper = new HtmlHelper(new ViewContext(ControllerContext, new WebFormView(ControllerContext, "Index"), new ViewDataDictionary(), new TempDataDictionary(), new System.IO.StringWriter()), new ViewPage());
      helper.RenderAction("Index2");//call your action

      return View();
  }

  public ActionResult Index2(/*your arg*/)
  {
      //your code
      return new EmptyResult();
  }
  ```