# What is the proper way to ensure SSL in Asp.Net 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building a new ASP.NET 5 website with MVC/Web Api, and hosting this on an Azure Website.  I currently am running with beta 8.

My problems came when I built a controller with a POST method.  Whenever I would deploy to my Azure Website calling the POST always results in a 502 Bad Gateway Error. "The CGI Application encountered an error and the server terminated the process".  This same method works locally.

After a troubleshooting the issues I traced the problem down to a piece of Middleware I wrote that essentially sends a 302 Redirect whenever the request comes in on HTTP.  The 302 sends the requests to the same host/path/query only on HTTPS.

When I remove this middleware the POST Works.  Obviously this is causing the issue, but I have 2 questions.

1. Why would redirecting to HTTPS cause a failure to execute the POST
2. What is the proper way to ensure that requests come in over HTTPS.

My Middleware code:

```
if(!context.Request.IsHttps){
    var withHttps = "https://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.Path;
    if(context.Request.QueryString.HasValue){
      withHttps += context.Request.QueryString.Value;
    }
    context.Response.Redirect(withHttps);
}
else{
    if(m_Next != null)
       await m_Next(context);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is redirecting changes your POST HTTP command to GET command.

You have two choices:

- Change your controller action to accept GET command;
- Change your middle ware and have it to POST instead of redirecting;

Just found [this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129335/how-do-you-redirect-to-a-page-using-the-post-verb), it has information that might help you:

Comment: Yep.  I was almost ready to answer my own question.  After posting the question, and going to dinner I was thinking about the workflow and realized my error in thinking.  

Thanks for the response.  I am actually going to just block POSTs on non SSL traffic.  My requirements are such that I can't allow them anyway, and as of now they should be executed from the web page I deliver.  If I redirect the GET for the web page to SSL then all subsequent posts from that page will be SSL too.

Comment: You should've gone to dinner a little earlier :-).  Sounds like you've got a good plan, good luck!