# Redirect to action not working correctly in my controller in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong here.

I have a .get() in javascript that calls my controller and in the controllers action I want to redirect to another action. The problem is the redirect enters "Events" but doesn't load the page/view and I get a error coming back from the get call. I'm following advice from this SO thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129335/how-do-you-redirect-to-a-page-using-the-post-verb) by Jason Bunting. The error from the .get says

> The view 'JumbotronSearch' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
> ~/Views/Home/JumbotronSearch.aspx
> ~/Views/Home/JumbotronSearch.ascx
> ~/Views/Shared/JumbotronSearch.aspx
> ~/Views/Shared/JumbotronSearch.ascx
> ~/Views/Home/JumbotronSearch.cshtml
> ~/Views/Home/JumbotronSearch.vbhtml
> ~/Views/Shared/JumbotronSearch.cshtml
> ~/Views/Shared/JumbotronSearch.vbhtml

Here is the javascript

```js
$.get(scope.enumControllers.jumbotronSearch, model, function(result) {
  if (result.error == true) {
    yb.base.displayNotification(result.message, 'danger');
  }
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  yb.base.displayNotification("Oh no! Something went wrong sending your request. Please contact the  help desk.", 'danger');
});
```

Here is my controller code

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult JumbotronSearch(SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Events", new { searchCriteria = searchCriteria });
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Events(SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
    {
        try
        {
            var viewModel = new EventsViewModel();
            //do some work here

            return View(viewModel);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log exception in file or db or both
            return Json(new { error = "true", message = "Oh No! Something happened trying to submit your search. Please contact Help Desk." });
        }
    }
```

Comment: `$.post()` is an ajax call. Ajax calls never redirect (the whole point of using it is to stay on the same page). If you want to redirect, just make a normal submit.

Comment: but even if he is inside the JumbotronSearch it won't redirect because of the post action verb on the Events action method ? @StephenMuecke

Comment: @SaadK, Assuming OP makes a normal submit, then that is one issue, as is the fact that it needs to be `return RedirectToAction("Events", new { searchCriteria = searchCriteria });` - but posting to one method which immediately redirects to another method makes no sense anyway

Comment: ok so I use a .get instead but now I get some error in the get error response that says "This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet" are my return values incorrect?

Comment: I had the exact same error and I solved it by changing the call, let me re post my answer because I can't put the code in here

Comment: I'm editing my original question with a different approach found in a SO thread, but am still not having luck. Getting some .get response error.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because your action method is POST, have a look at the answer here 
[How do you redirect to a page using the POST verb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129335/how-do-you-redirect-to-a-page-using-the-post-verb)

You can change the action verbs in the Events method to

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
```

or you can change the action method call to this

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public void JumbotronSearch(SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
{
    Return Events (searchCriteria);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect a post and thus your call to

```
$.post
```

will end up at `JumbotronSearch` but not redirected to `Events`

Use an `HTTP GET` instead

```
$.get(scope.enumControllers.jumbotronSearch, model, function(result) {


[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public void JumbotronSearch(SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
{
    RedirectToAction("Events");
}
```

see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129335/how-do-you-redirect-to-a-page-using-the-post-verb)

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. It doesn't enter into the "Events" action.

Comment: @user1186050 where does it get to ?

Comment: it gets to RedirectToAction() and then nothing!! no exception, no response in ajax...I'm confused!

Comment: @user1186050 try simply `RedirectToAction("Events");` - use fiddler to see what is going on

Comment: tried it and it just stepped over the redirecttoaction. this is frustrating

Comment: it will step over it that is normal - it will instruct the browser to re-issue the request... you need to press f12 and see what requests are being sent by your browser.
Why dont you simply call the method ? eg `return Events (searchCriteria);`

Comment: when I try return Events(...) I get the same error as my post says and no new page loading. The view()  in "Events" does get hit in the code though

Comment: @user1186050 'no new page loading' - your call to `$.get` or `$.post` will never do that, its an ajax call!