# ASP.NET Core: redirect from GET to POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to call `MarriageById` as GET, like this:

```
var url = '/MarriageById?id=' + id;
```

But I also want to have a single `ActionResult Marriage(Marriage marriage)` that does some processing before showing the view. This second one must be `POST` because it will also receive the "send form" from asp.

I am trying [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1343182/831138) (see my own implementation below), but it is still redirected as a GET and `ActionResult Marriage` is not found:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MarriageById(int id)
{
    var marriage = _marriageRepository.GetById(id);
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Marriage), marriage);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Marriage(Marriage marriage)
{
    var people = _personRepository.GetAll();

    ViewBag.men = Utils.GetPersonsSelectListByGender(people, isMale: true);
    ViewBag.women = Utils.GetPersonsSelectListByGender(people, isMale: false);

    return View(marriage);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `RedirectToAction` always implies a GET, so this won't work to reach the `Marriage` action method that only accepts POST.

However there is nothing wrong with calling the other method yourself, it is still a method like any other. So try this instead:

```
return Marriage(marriage);
```

And on a side note: if the `Marriage` method will always only be used to display data, and *never* to save, store or change data, then using POST is not the best choice. POST typically implies a call with side effects (save, store, change, or even delete), and in general it is best to stick to that convention.

Comment: I was using `RedirectToAction` instead of  `return Marriage(marriage);` because it then goes find the `View` of `MarriageById` (and not `Marriage`). Of course this can be solved if you fix the underlying view return as `return View('Marriage');`. But I searched a bit and people recommended `RedirectToAction`, and I guess I got some concepts mixed up after that. Thanks for the detailed answer, marking it as solved because it provides a solution and not just the info.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should mix GET with POST verbs. They are just semantically different. 
If you have a similar functionality that you want to execute for those 2 methods, maybe instead of calling POST from GET you might want to extract the common parts ot some other 'private' method or even layer (depending on the use case).

Hope it makes sense