# Redirect to URL with POST method in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, url, redirect, url-rewriting, asp.net-core

I have simple url rewriter:

```
    private static void RedirectToAPI(RewriteContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        if (request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/apiendpoint", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {           
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request.Path.Value
                .Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Skip(1));
            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

            response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = $"/custom";
            response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently;
            context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
            using (var bodyWriter = new StreamWriter(response.Body))
            {
                bodyWriter.Write(json);
                bodyWriter.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is, when it redirects to */custom* url, request has method GET, while this method require POST.

For example, send GET request to url */apiendpoint/first/second/third*, then rewriter responds to redirect, accordingly, the following request must be with method POST, but now, it is GET.

How can I change method of request, which is after url rewriter response?

Comment: Did you try `request.Method = "POST"`?

Comment: @Gururaj yes, nothing changes, still GET request.

Comment: request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;?

Comment: @Gururaj absolutely the same as the previous. However, `request.Method` changes method of incoming request before rewrite, while I need after.

Comment: Gosh!, How could I miss this - my apologies. Looking at your code I'm seeing you're not redirecting internally on the server but you're creating a response to redirect the request to another URI. Did you try using `DelegatingHandler` implementation and overriding `SendAsync` method to change the request method. **This works unless you're not trying to redirect to external URI.**

Comment: @Gururaj Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Just to be clear. a) Your initial request - is it a POST or a GET? b) You want that initial request to result in a redirect that is a POST (is that correct)?

Comment: @mjwills initial request is GET, I want it redirect to POST, that's it.

Comment: I suspect even if you manage to get the web server to serve up a redirect to a POST endpoint the browser won't 'honour' it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47735/34092 .

Comment: @mjwills so, it must be an internal redirect, mustn't it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'internal redirect'. In terms of how to solve this, check out the link I provided.

Comment: also looks on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225936/asp-net-core-redirect-from-get-to-post

Comment: You probably are looking for this: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5609. It was fixed, and is now live in 2.0.0-preview1.

Comment: @juunas I am not sure that github link will help here, since the person who asked this question explicitly does not want preservation of HTTP method.

Comment: @mjwills Yeah, I read all of the comments after I posted mine :) It certainly won't work. The way most people achieve a GET->POST switch is to return an auto-submitting form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Ah, just now checked the comments. If the initial request is a GET, then this won't work either and you can't tell the browser to POST. Not without returning a view that auto-executes a form with JavaScript.

You need to return a 308, not a 301.

Here is the changed code:

```
private static void RedirectToAPI(RewriteContext context)
{
    var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
    if (request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/apiendpoint", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {           
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request.Path.Value
            .Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Skip(1));
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = $"/custom";
        response.StatusCode = 308;
        context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
        using (var bodyWriter = new StreamWriter(response.Body))
        {
            bodyWriter.Write(json);
            bodyWriter.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

308 is a permanent redirect that requires the browser to preserve the method. https://httpstatuses.com/308

The temporary version is 307.

Convenience methods for these redirects are available in MVC Core 2.0.0-preview1.

Answer (score 2):

If using ASP.NET Core 2.0 there is RedirectPermanentPreserveMethod, you can read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirectpermanentpreservemethod?view=aspnetcore-5.0). If this method is not supported you can try doing it manually.

Comment: with asp.net core 3.1 I am able to use RedirectPermanentPreserveMethod to post data.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a sample code**

```
public class ConvertGetToPostHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Add your logic here to decide if the request Method needs to be changed
        // Caution: This works only if you're redirecting internally
        request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

You will have to add the Handler to Handler Pipeline as

`config.MessageHandlers.Add(new ConvertGetToPostHandler());`

Also, read over this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers) to get some insight into it's purpose and usage.

Comment: there is no DelegatingHandler in ASP.NET Core. [Middlewares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/http-modules) are used instead

Comment: Sorry mate. Looks looks like today is not my day. Sorry for wasting your time. I've not worked on Core yet :(

Comment: Check this reference [Migrating Http Handler to Core middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/http-modules), if it helps

Comment: Your method is fine, although as previously mentioned, in Asp.Net Core there is Middleware, which is what I were looking for my purpose.

Comment: @YuriyN. Thanks for acknowledging my methodology. I've shared a reference earlier which describes migrating from Handler to Core Middleware. Please read the reference and see if that can be of any help to you.

Answer (score 1):

Can you set @juunas answer as a correct answer, his answer solved it for me as you can see in my example code.

```
internal class RedirectCultureRule : IRule
{
    private const string CultureKey = "culture";

    public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        HttpRequest httpRequest = context.HttpContext.Request;
        httpRequest.Query.TryGetValue(CultureKey, out StringValues cultureValues);
        string culture = cultureValues;

        if (cultureValues.Count > 0 && culture.IsCultureMatch())
        {
            context.Result = RuleResult.ContinueRules;
            return;
        }

        Dictionary<string, string> queryParts = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        NameValueCollection queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(httpRequest.QueryString.ToString());

        foreach (string key in queryString)
        {
            queryParts[key.Trim()] = queryString[key].Trim();
        }

        if (!queryParts.ContainsKey(CultureKey))
        {
            queryParts[CultureKey] = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;
        }

        string query = $"?{string.Join("&", queryParts.Select(qp => $"{qp.Key}={qp.Value}"))}";

        if (query.Length > 1)
        {
            httpRequest.QueryString = new QueryString(query);
        }

        string url = UriHelper.GetDisplayUrl(httpRequest);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = context.HttpContext.Response;
        httpResponse.StatusCode = 308;
        httpResponse.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = url;

        using (StreamReader requestReader = new StreamReader(httpRequest.Body))
        {
            using (StreamWriter responseWriter = new StreamWriter(httpResponse.Body))
            {
                string body = requestReader.ReadToEnd();
                responseWriter.Write(body);
                responseWriter.Flush();
            }
        }

        context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
    }
}
```