# how to send user to another page (external url) with post method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, httpcontext

i want to redirect user to payment page in asp.net core with post method.

i did it in asp.net like this:

```
    public void Post()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<html><head>");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("</head><body onload=\"document.{0}.submit()\">", m_FormName));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<form name=\"{0}\" method=\"{1}\" action=\"{2}\" >", m_FormName, m_Method, m_Url));
        for (int i = 0; i < Inputs.Keys.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<input name=\"{0}\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"{1}\">", Inputs.Keys[i], Inputs[Inputs.Keys[i]]));
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</form>");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</body></html>");
    }
```

should i use:

```
HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync
```

if yes how it work if so many line write by await.

is there any better way to do that?

Comment: I'm confused. The question has nothing to do with the code provided?

Comment: i want to forward user from myPage to payment page in external url with post methd

Comment: @JamesS: the OP wants to have the page first post to his server, and then post to someone else’s server.  Or at least that is what he is currently doing and is asking about replicating.

Comment: @jmoreno Ah, from my understanding of the title, I thought he wanted the user to be redirected to an external URL

Comment: @JamesS: yes, as part of a two step process (not sure that is what is desired, or just what currently works for the OP).

Comment: ues i mean redirect user but need to pass data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're wanting to do is not possible. There is no way to make the client issue a POST. You can't make the client do *anything*. You can *suggest* that they request another URL (a redirect), but it's 100% up to the client whether or not to actually do that, and when and if the client does, it will be requested via GET only.

The only way to start a flow like this is to present the user with an HTML form with a submit button and an action of where you want them to go to begin the flow. It is then on the client to click that button.

Comment: with code provided i did it in asp.net web api. it's working now. and i dont know how to implement this in asp.net core

Answer (score 0):

You can use redirect with status code 308, I think this answer is the best '[Redirect to URL with POST method in Asp.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312938/4835498)'