# How to RedirectToAction specifying the action http method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to execute a POST action by redirecting to another controller. My issue is how to do it with two same name actions.

CartLinesController.cs

```
// GET: CartLines/Create
    public IActionResult Create(){}

   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Create(parameters){}
```

I'm calling these actions from another controller.

ProductsController.cs

```
public IActionResult AddToCart(int id)
    {
        TempData["ProductId"] = id;
        return RedirectToAction("Create", "CartLines");
    }
```

The issue is this RedirectToAction is calling the GET: Create action instead of the POST one. Is there a way to specify this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect to URL with POST method in Asp.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44307459/redirect-to-url-with-post-method-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: Not really. I added [HttpPost] on the AddToCart action, but it didn't work. It goes to this path: https://localhost:port/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FProducts%2FAddToCart%2F2 instead of going to https://localhost:port/Products/AddToCart/2 and then redirect to the CartLines Create Post action

Answer (score 2):

HTTP doesn't support redirection to a page using POST. When you redirect somewhere, the HTTP "Location" header tells the browser where to go, and the browser makes a GET request for that page.

You can redirect to the Get method first, and pass a bool value to distinguish whether to execute automatically or manually. For example:

```
public IActionResult AddToCart(int id)
{
    TempData["ProductId"] = id;
    return RedirectToAction("Create", "CartLines",new { parameter = true});
}

public IActionResult Create(bool? parameter)
{
    ViewData["parameter"] = parameter;
    return View();
}
```

Then judge whether `ViewData["parameter"]` exists in the view, and if so, use JavaScript to automatically call the post method.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it manually. First of all redirect to a GET route. In that route, return a HIDDEN form with auto-submit (maybe javascript wise) to your POST action with POST method.

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections), HTTP-redirection does not support POST out of the box.