# return RedirectToAction("Edit", Model)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Afternoon Folks,

I have a question in reference to how to redirect to another model within my mvc project.

I have a controller with CRUD operations, and i have a [HttpPost] action on Create.  The system saves the data to the database as required but instead of me sending the user back to the "Index" page i want to sent them to another model.

I know how to use the redirect option...

```
 // POST: CarerDetailsNew/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]     
    public ActionResult Create(CarerViewModel carerViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.CarerDetails.Add(carerViewModel.carer);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", carerViewModel.carer);
            //return RedirectToRoute("ClientRecordsController");
        }


        return View(carerViewModel);
    }
```

However i have read that i may be able to use the "RedirectToRoute" option to get back to another model.

The model that i am in is my "Carer" model but i want to get back to my "Client" model and specifically the "Edit".

I have tried to replace my RedirectToAction to one of the following but this fails to see the "Client" model.

```
return RedirectToRoute("Edit", clientViewRecord.client);
```

Or

```
 return RedirectToRoute(ClientRecordsController, "Edit", clientViewRecord.client);
```

Any suggestions are more than welcome as i am struggling to get this to work.

Regards
Betty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you redirect to a page using the POST verb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129335/how-do-you-redirect-to-a-page-using-the-post-verb)

Comment: Also *fails to see the "Client" model* well you most not be populating this. You must send all data you require to the server or get it again from it's source. It won't persist.

Comment: @Liam,  many thanks, i will take a look at the above link.

Comment: `RedirectToAction` should work just fine. Try `return RedirectToAction("ClientRecords", "Edit", new { model = clientViewRecord.client });`

Comment: Visual Studio won't recognize a build error if you use a string to redirect to another action or controller whose name has changed. You can use return RedirectToAction(nameof(Action), nameof(Controller), new { parameters });