# Redirection target returns a Not Found Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am wrestling with anomalous behavior in an IActionResult execution sequence in a .net core 2.0 web app.  I have a controller action that gets user input from a DatePicker Form.  The date is the parameter then used used to access both SQL Server and CosmosDB. Currently the code is being developed on my local machine, but other other versions of it are published and run successfully on Azure as web apps.
Getting the date info works great.  Redirecting from the get date post invokes the target controller action correctly but does not return the associated view page.  There are no build errors nor on the Chrome console - the datepicker page is still active. Invoking the target page via other means like from the home page menu it works fine.  Single stepping the execution sequence debugging using VS 2017 (v 15.9.6) reveals no anomalies.
Examining breakpoints in the GetDate post and in ShaftReport reveals all vars and steps as expected.  Another variation of the return View("~/Views/Home/ShaftReport.cshtml") has the same behavior.

Code :
Home Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetDate()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetDate(string di)
{
    // this is correct
    DateTime sdi = Convert.ToDateTime(di);

    // no param passed for test
    return RedirectToAction("ShaftReport");
}

public IActionResult ShaftReport()
{
    // appears to execute but ShaftReport page not showing but GetDate page still active
    return View();
}
```

What's missing and/or wrong ?

Comment: What do you get from networking sniffer (Development Tools > Network)? Maybe you can get more info from there (StatusCode, Responde Body, etc.)

Comment: You may need to take a look on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/129361/2260875

Comment: Got a fix.  I was using an ajax javascript post for the datepicker return value, which turned out to be the problem.  I changed the javascript function to use window.location.href instead and now it works as expected.