# What to put in place of LocalRedirect in case of POST call : POST call ERROR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, controller

In the following method that processes the login request: in case of login ok I have to call a page in post. The post call has one parameter and for the call I use standard http method.

The speech of the **LocalRedirect** then declines. What should I put in order to make all working?

I indicated the point in the code with the TO DO.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
        }

        // Se non viene passato un url specifico lo setto sul default
        model.ReturnUrl = model.ReturnUrl ?? Url.Content("/Telemetries/Pagina2");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");

                //activity log
                ApplicationUser CurrentUser = await GetCurrentUserAsyncbyUsername(model.Username);
                _activityLogService.InsertActivity(CurrentUser,
                    "LoginUser",
                    "User Logged ({0})",
                    model.Username,
                    CurrentUser.Id);

                List<DeviceSetup> devices = _deviceService.GetList(CurrentUser.CustomerId);

                if (devices!=null && devices.Count!=0)
                {
                    Devices device = _deviceService.GetDeviceByDeviceId(devices[0].DeviceId);


                    // TO DO
                    await WebExtensions.RedirectWithData(device.SerialNo, model.ReturnUrl, HttpContext);

                }
                else
                {
                    model.ReturnUrl = Url.Content("~/");
                    return LocalRedirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                }
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = model.ReturnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View();
    }
```

The POST call seems not call the page. I put a breakpoint in the controller of the called page but it never stops here. For the post call I use the method explained here : [Response.Redirect with POST instead of Get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/response-redirect-with-post-instead-of-get/2802848#2802848) as suggested me by Claudio Cayo Castagnetti.

Thanks in advance.

Simone

Comment: Hi Simone, I suggest you look at this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129335/how-do-you-redirect-to-a-page-using-the-post-verb
and this workaround:
https://gist.github.com/priore/7163408

Comment: I believe that this trick can also do for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2802848/2427812

Comment: @ClaudioCayoCastagnetti : 
I tried both solutions but unfortunately they don't solve the problem