# redirectToAction is resetting array

Tags: c#, razor, redirecttoaction

Hello I am using C# for this web application and I am trying to pass a object stdnt through redirectToAction. But when it refreshes and goes to index skillResults is always empty. I step through to the end of the submit and it has all the correct information but it is reset when I step through the index. Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    public IActionResult Index(Student stdnt)
    {
        return View(stdnt);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// submit student skills
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="con"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> submit(Student stdnt)
    {
        stdnt = IsValidStudent(stdnt);
        if (stdnt.warning == "")
        {
            //initialize arrays
            stdnt.skillResults = new SkillResult[9];
            for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                stdnt.skillResults[i] = new SkillResult();
                stdnt.skillResults[i].skill_name = "";
                stdnt.skillResults[i].skill_type = "";
                stdnt.skillResults[i].description = "";
                stdnt.skillResults[i].importance = "";
            }

            stdnt.success = true;
            //find skills for the three jobs listed
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stdnt.JobNames[i]))
                {
                    var jobList = new List<Job>();
                    jobList = await getJobs(stdnt.JobNames[i]);

                    var jobSkills = new JobSkills();
                    jobSkills = await getJobSkills(jobList[i].uuid);

                    //find top three skills based on importance level
                    var importantSkills = new List<Skill>();
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    {
                        importantSkills.Add(new Skill() { level = 0 });
                    }
                    for (int j = 0; j < jobSkills.skills.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (jobSkills.skills[j].level > importantSkills[0].level)
                        {
                            importantSkills[0] = jobSkills.skills[j];
                        }
                        else if (jobSkills.skills[j].level > importantSkills[1].level)
                        {
                            importantSkills[1] = jobSkills.skills[j];
                        }
                        else if (jobSkills.skills[j].level > importantSkills[2].level)
                        {
                            importantSkills[2] = jobSkills.skills[j];
                        }
                    }

                    //set students results
                    for(int j = 0;j < 3; j++)
                    {
                        stdnt.skillResults[j + i * 3].skill_name = importantSkills[j].skill_name;
                        stdnt.skillResults[j + i * 3].skill_type = importantSkills[j].skill_type;
                        stdnt.skillResults[j + i * 3].description = importantSkills[j].description;
                        stdnt.skillResults[j + i * 3].importance = importantSkills[j].importance.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            stdnt.success = false;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", stdnt);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Courtwright (https://stackoverflow.com/a/129361/14879818) post does not support redirection.

In order to receive your object `stdnt`, you need to use the decorator `[HttpGet]`.