# asp.net core 7.0 RedirectToAction method send route values as post

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-7.0

in my asp.net core 7.0 web app, I have been using `RedirectToAction(string? actionName, string? controllerName, object? routeValues)` and it was fine but it sends the route values as `Get`, is there any way to make it send the values as `Post` ?

I tried to use `RedirectToRoute()` but it doesn't have any actionName or controllerName init.

Comment: Redirects are to gets not posts.

Comment: You can use the tag helper  or ajax to call the method in the view.

Comment: [How do you redirect to a page using the POST](https://stackoverflow.com/q/129335/6630084)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are both in the same controller you can call it directly.

Below is a demo, you can refer to it:

```
  public IActionResult Index()
{
    //return View();
    string UserName = "aa";
    int Id = 1;
    return Postdata(UserName,Id);
}


[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Postdata(string UserName,int Id)
{
    return View();
}
```

result:

[image]

**Update:**
In different controllers, you can use httpClient to pass the data:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{           
    var model=new User() {Name = "aa",Id = 1};
    JsonContent content = JsonContent.Create(model);
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://localhost:7208/Another/Postdata", content);
    return View();
    
}
```

AnotherController:

```
public class AnotherController : Controller
{
    
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Postdata([FromBody] User user)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

User:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

result:
[image]

Comment: No in different controllers

Comment: @AbdelrahmanAlmowafy  Please have a look at my update answer.