# Post from one controller action to another (not redirect)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, post

I have an action which I need to post forward onto another action if it meets certain conditions, but I am unable to preserve the form data when passing through to the next action.

The receiving action accepts a FormCollection, which the sending action

Currently, I am doing a return RedirectToAction("action","controller", form). And I can determine that the form variable has keys before it redirects (form.HasKeys() = true).

When the action is hit however, the FormCollection is empty (form.HasKeys() = false).

Any ideas? Is there a 'PostToAction' method that I am missing?

FYI: I am using ASP.NET MVC Beta. Many thanks!

**Edit:** For those who have this problem, please look into the [PRG Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). This is the actual term of what I was looking to do which also enables pretty urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When RedirectToAction is called it will make an HTTP redirection and it will make a GET to the other action URL. If you need to reuse the code from another controller I'd do what ewalshe suggest, move the common to a BaseController or a business service and make both actions delegate to it.

This links may help:

- [ASP.NET
      MVC Tip #6 – Call RedirectToAction
      after Submitting a Form](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/06/20/asp-net-mvc-tip-6-call-redirecttoaction-after-submitting-a-form.aspx)
- [How
  to RedirectToAction in ASP.NET MVC
  (Preview 4) without losing request
  data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936/how-to-redirecttoaction-in-aspnet-mvc-preview-4-without-losing-request-data)

Comment: Eduardo, thankyou for the linkage! It helped looking at Stephen Walther's example.

Answer (score 2):

I would refactor the two controllers and put the common code into a helper or into a common base class. That way the actions in the two controllers can delegate to the common code.