# asp.net- mvc pass variables from one controller (action) to another controller (action)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action

i have an AccountController that does the asp.net login and user registration. (Register action below.. After that is successful i also want to add this user data to another table of mind called users.  Right now i have a "UsersController" and an action called "Create" so as you can see below i have the line:

```
return RedirectToAction("Create", "Users");
```

Here is the full registration method

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Register(string userName, string email, string password, string confirmPassword, string address, string address2, string city, string state, string homePhone, string cellPhone, string company)
    {
        ViewData["PasswordLength"] = MembershipService.MinPasswordLength;
        if (ValidateRegistration(userName, email, password, confirmPassword))
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus =        MembershipService.CreateUser(userName, password, email);

            if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                FormsAuth.SignIn(userName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
                return RedirectToAction("Create", "Users");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View();
    }
```

my issue is that i want to pass all of the arguments (userName, email, address, etc) into my action as these are fields in the users table as well

How do i pass arguments to this other action or is there some other recommended practices to do multiple actions at once and keep the state of the variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use tempData [How to RedirectToAction in ASP.NET MVC without losing request data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936/how-to-redirecttoaction-in-asp-net-mvc-without-losing-request-data)

Comment: isn't there a cleaner way . . using tempdata seems a bit implicit as there is all this state hanging around in these dictionaries as opposed to being explicit arguments being passed from one method to another