# Is There An Equivalent to redirect_to :back in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc

Is there an equivalent to Ruby On Rails' **redirect_to :back** in ASP.NET MVC?

What about *after* submitting a form? For example:

From page1 user clicks a link to page2. Submits a form on page2, then I want to redirect to page1.

This works great if I hard code the redirect to go to Page1.  However if the user clicks a link to page2 from page8, after submitting the form on page2, how can I redirect back to page 8 instead of page1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use Jan's code as the **return** value of your action then just drop the **Response.** part as Response.Redirect will return void. You could do this instead...

```
public ActionResult Index()
{    
    return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
}
```

If you are posting back to a form then take a look at this SO question, it might help.

[How to RedirectToAction in ASP.NET MVC without losing request data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936/how-to-redirecttoaction-in-asp-net-mvc-without-losing-request-data)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a reference to the previouspage from code, with Page.PreviousPage; though I'm not sure whether this exists in MVC.

You can also just redirect to the referrer:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
```

Comment: This works, but what if you are posting back from a form? I'll have to look into how Rails handles this.