# How to pass model data to one controller to another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

pass model data to one controller to another controller is possible?

I want to passe the model data to one controller ro another controller.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Personal(StudentModel student)
        {                          
                return RedirectToAction("nextStep", new { model = student});          
        }

        public ActionResult nextStep(StudentModel model)
        {           
            return View(model);
        }
```

in `nextStep` controller model value is null.
How to do it?
I need to StudentModel data in nextStep conreoller.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing data between different controller action methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385442/passing-data-between-different-controller-action-methods)

Answer (score 10):

You are using `RedirectToAction`. It will issue GET request. There are two ways you can pass your model here.

**1. TempData**

You need to persist the model in TempData and make `RedirectToAction`. However the restriction is it will be available only for the immediate request. In your case, it is not a problem. You can do it with `TempData`

```
public ActionResult Personal(StudentModel student)
{                          
       TempData["student"] = student;
       return RedirectToAction("nextStep", "ControllerName");          
}

public ActionResult nextStep()
{      
       StudentModel model= (StudentModel) TempData["student"];
       return View(model);
}
```

**2. Passing in a query string**

As the request is GET, we can pass the data as Query string with the model property name. MVC model binder will resolve the query string and convert it as model.

```
 return RedirectToAction("nextStep", new { Name = model.Name, Age=model.Age });
```

Also take a note ***passing sensible data in a Query string is not advisable***.