# How to pass any POST parameter with the model entities from one Action to another Action in MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, action

Well, I have 2 actions in different controller but the work procedure is almost same however their input parameter are slightly different. One action is receiving some `POST` parameter in addition with model where as  other action does not.  So I would like to call  one action from another controller through the different action. Therefore I need to pass the `POST` parameters as well. So what do I do?

For example My Main Action is like in `ProcedureController` controller

```
public virtual byte[] GenerateProcedureReports(Report model)
{
      procedureListIds = Request.Form["ProcedureMultiCheckList"].Trim();
}
```

Look here I am receiving `procedureListIds` from  `Form request` So if I redirect any route to this action how do I send this parameter `ProcedureMultiCheckList`

I have tried this way by studying this Questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27774235/how-to-pass-model-data-to-one-controller-to-another-controller), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385442/passing-data-between-different-controller-action-methods), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989474/how-to-pass-values-from-one-controller-to-another-controller-in-asp-net-mvc3). However I didn't get any solution regarding to this problem.

I have tried by this way from `ProcedureJobsController`

```
        public virtual ActionResult JobReport(long id)
        {
            var jobInformation = _procedureJobService.Get(id);
            if (jobInformation.IsFromTablet)
            {
                Report report = new Report();
                return RedirectToAction("GenerateProcedureReports", "Procedures", new {report =report,  ProcedureMultiCheckList = jobInformation.ProcedureId });
            }
}
```

Here I have tried to pass model and the `POST` parameter(`ProcedureMultiCheckList`), but it is not receiving as a `Form request` parameter. So, how do I solve this problem?
If this can be done I will be able to reduce thousands line of code. Pretty pathetic, Huh?

Comment: Couple of clarification before I post an answer: `Report model` where is it coming from - also POST of form? Also, is there a particular requirement of issuing a redirect rather than fulfilling the request?

Comment: Question 1. Yes, Report model is coming from  a POST of a form. 
Question 2. Yes. I have a different requirement therefore I can't combine the actions. I need to fulfill some other extra work the  I am redirecting the action.

Comment: Can you clarify Q2 for me - what is that requirement that cannot be handled inline on the request.  Usually it is something like returning partial data to client so client can submit additional info, but I don't see it here, hence why I'm trying to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like this:

```
public virtual ActionResult JobReport(long id)
{
    var jobInformation = _procedureJobService.Get(id);
    if (jobInformation.IsFromTablet)
    {
        Report report = new Report();
        TempData["ProcedureMultiCheckList"] = jobInformation.ProcedureId;
         return RedirectToAction("GenerateProcedureReports", "Procedures", new {report = report });
    }
}
```

reading TempData:

```
var procedureMultiCheckList = TempData["ProcedureMultiCheckList"]
```

Comment: I don't have any property in `Report` model which named `ProcedureMultiCheckList`   If anything is taken from request then there is no need to keep it in the model.

Comment: In that case you cannot pass as a parameter. You can either update the model to persist the data in another way .e.g. TempData, see updated example.

Comment: Your procedure seems that it is possible, but I have to change something from my controller. But I will do that if `var procedureMultiCheckList = TempData["ProcedureMultiCheckList"]` for `POST` method seperately.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
  public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
  {
    return RedirectToAction("MySimilarAction", "About", new{model=model, age=40, name="my Name"});
  }
}


public class AboutController: Controller
{
  public ActionResult MySimilarAction(MyModel model, int age, string name)
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: In that case I need to change my action parameters, but I will not do so.