# How to fix passed list parameter value being 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

I am trying to pass a list of values to another method however once that 2nd method is called the list loses it's value.

First Method:

```
public ActionResult Create_Filter([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<CourseFilterViewModel> courseFilterVM)
    {
var results = new List<Results>
        {
            new Results {CourseNumber = "100", CourseTitle = "Test Title", CourseSubject = "Subject Test"}
        };

        return RedirectToAction("TestView", "Filter", new {results});

}
```

2nd Method:

```
public ActionResult TestView(List<Results> results)
    {
        //results value here is 0               

        return null;
    }
```

I expect the output of: CourseNumber = "100", CourseTitle = "Test Title", CourseSubject = "Subject Test")

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22206069/5394220

Comment: @crmckain, You asked the same question again. I have already answered your question here. Please check it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54489088/5928070

Comment: @TanvirArjel I was trying a different approach and was getting different results so I thought it warranted another question.

Comment: Okay! got it. Let see what can we do for you.

Comment: Don't worry it worked anyways. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

when you're doing the redirect to action, the parameter is passed as a querystring so you can't pass an entire object, see this issue:
[passing object in redirecttoaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597863/passing-object-in-redirecttoaction)

Answer (score 0):

Try TempData.  The data will carry over to one redirect.

```
public ActionResult Create_Filter([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, 
[Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<CourseFilterViewModel> courseFilterVM)
{
    var results = new List<Results>
    {
        new Results {CourseNumber = "100", CourseTitle = "Test Title", 
         CourseSubject = "Subject Test"}
    };
    TempData["results"] = results;
    return RedirectToAction("TestView", "Filter");

 }
 public ActionResult TestView()
 {

    if(TempData["results"] != null) {
      //do something
    }
    return whatever;
 }
```