# Passing values using RedirectToAction Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I want to pass two variables from one action method to another action method using RedirectToAction.
i am able to send one variable or one object at a time.
Is it possible to send two or more values at a time?

Comment: Can you share the target action signature? Is it one from Uri and one from body?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385442/passing-data-between-different-controller-action-methods

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are taking about a GET request with multiple query parameters on the URL.

```
return RedirectToAction("action", "controller", new {
           id = 1,
           searchParamOne = "value", 
           anotherParam = "value2" 
       });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help .my actual requirements was this to passing multiple variables using RedirectToAction.
It is working fine.

Comment: Glad I could help, don't forget to accept working answers

Answer (score 1):

Put the values into the TempData dictionary.

```
TempData["ValueOne"] = "SomeValue"
TempData["ValueTwo"] = "SomeOtherValue"
```

In the second method after the redirect, get the values out of TempData:

```
var val1 = TempData["ValueOne"]; 
var val2 = TempData["ValueTwo"];
```

Here is a link to the docs on the TempData dictionary:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2