# Passing data between controllers ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So, I'm creating a basic time table application, and I want to pass the user name to another controller like that:

//POST

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Index(Login obj)
{
    return RedirectToAction(actionName:
        "Index", controllerName:
        "EmploiDuTemps", obj.Name);
}
```

and I try to receive it on the other controller like this :

```
public IActionResult Index(string obj)
{
   
    return View(obj);
}
```

so I can use it the view, but it doesn't work, can someone help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385442/passing-data-between-different-controller-action-methods 

here

Comment: @KOMODO thanks for your help but unfortunatly the answer is depreciated with mvc 5 but it gave me a different pov on my problem, thanks

Comment: return RedirectToAction(actionName:
        "Index", controllerName:
        "EmploiDuTemps", new{obj=obj.Name});  


... try this

Comment: Try to pass route values like this `return RedirectToAction("Index", "EmploiDuTemps", new { obj = obj.Name });`