# How to pass variables from one controller to another

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic, controllers

I would like to pass the variables to the other Controllers TableName, 
I'm trying to ViewBag.Variable but do send  the null.

if you can pass these parameters from one controller to another 
thank you very much in advance for the help

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string NombreVariable = "TablaUsuario";
        ViewBag.Variable = NombreVariable;
        return View();    
    }



    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult GridViewPartial()
    {


        var entity = (IEnumerable)db.GetType()
                       .GetProperty(ViewBag.Variable)
                       .GetValue(db, null);
        var model = entity.Cast<object>();
        return PartialView("_GridViewPartial", model);


    }

  [HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]

    public ActionResult GridViewPartialAddNew()
    {
        var entity = (dynamic)db.GetType() 
                       .GetProperty(ViewBag.Variable)
                       .GetValue(db, null);
        var model = entity;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            try
            {
                Model.TableUsuario tb = new Model.TableUsuario();

                int contador=tb.GetType().GetProperties().Count();
                 //Coleccion[] cual = new Coleccion[contador];
                 int contadores = 0;
                string[] valores = new string[contador];

                foreach( var i in tb.GetType().GetProperties())
                {

                    valores[contadores] = "'" + Convert.ToString(GridViewExtension.GetEditValue<dynamic>(i.Name)) + "' AS " + i.Name ;


                    contadores += 1;

                }
                db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("insert into TableUsuario SELECT " + string.Join(",",valores));
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ViewData["EditError"] = e.Message;
            }
        }
        else
            ViewData["EditError"] = "Please, correct all errors.";
        return PartialView("_GridViewPartial", model);
    }
```

Comment: can you show how are you accessing the ViewBag in your view

Comment: You use the ViewBag to pass data from the controller to the view. Not to pass data from controller to controller.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269376/passing-information-between-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call method_A in Controller_A, from Controller_B,  you can do it like this:

In Controller_B

```
Controller_A myControllerA = new Controller_A();
myControllerA.method_A(myVariable);
```

In Controller_A

```
public void method_A(MyClass myVariable)
...
...
```

Alternatively, if you want a "global" variable that is available everywhere, you can assign it to Session, in a similar way you use ViewBag

```
Session["myVariable"] = myVariable;
```

Though I would caution against using session: not everything belongs in the session state.

I guess it depends on exactly what you want to achieve.