# How to pass a variable from a controller to other controller using MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view that executes some conditions and if one specific condition is X it must redirect to another page and show a pop-up with a message, so I was thinking in a variable with the resul of the condition that is executed id the controller (controller1.cs) and then use it in another controller (Controller2.cs) for the next actions.

Any suggests?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385442/passing-data-between-different-controller-action-methods

Comment: return RedirectToAction("TestAction", "TestController", new {id = userId});

Comment: use a TempData object which contains your variable to be available in other action. And just read from tempData in second action. if so your url will be clean.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Sessions (you'll end up with using the Session as a kind of Singleton pattern with data you'll never use again). You want a `RedirectToAction` like this:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string myResult)
        {
            if (condition)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("OtherAction", "Controller2", myResult);
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

You can choose to use other controllers / actions with objects you want to pass.

Comment: Don't pass an object to a GET method, Apart from the ugly query string, it could exceed the query string character limit and throw an exception, and if the objects contains properties which are complex objects or collection binding will fail any way

Comment: changed it to string > wasn't about the object itself, it's an example of the routing. but thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

You can try using TempData -> http://www.devcurry.com/2012/05/what-is-aspnet-mvc-tempdata.html or Passing Information Between Controllers in ASP.Net-MVC -> [Passing Information Between Controllers in ASP.Net-MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269376/passing-information-between-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc).