# MVC 3/4 Pass Parameter from Controller to Another Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Login form, It asks for UserName, Password, TokenID (Each user knows his token, they get it to access an API). I would like to be able to Obtain that Token API that they entered and Pass it on to /Home/Index. What is the best way to go about doing that?

Comment: Is it only from one `Login` to `Home`? Or you may need it even after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first you have a View where user will be entering `UserName`, `Password` and `TokenId` so let the view have a model like the one shown below.

```
public class LoginModel{

public string UserName{get; set;} 
public string Password{get; set;}
public string TokenId{get; set;}
}
```

and from the view you can return this model, which will hold all these values.

Now as you need to pass these values to `Home/Index` you can have your form submitted to the `Index` action.

```
public ActionResult Index(LoginModel model)
{
 string gotcha = model.TokenId;
}
```

But incase if you want to submit a form to a different action of say a controller 'Login' and then pass this values to a different controller, you can do something like this.

```
// defined in Login Controller
public ActionResult Index(LoginModel model)
{
 TempData["TokenId"] = model.TokenId;
 return RedirectToAction("Dashboard","Account");
}

// defined in Account Controller
public ActionResult Dashboard()
{
 string gotVal = TempData["TokenId"]

}
```

there are more ways to pass values between two action, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3364045/1182982)