# How to redirect from an action to another action but provide its parameters in MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I know that you can make a redirection from an action to another like:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
   return View();
}

public ActionResult OtherAction(){
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Good. I didn't found a solution to my question: How to redirect to an action which has parameters ?
For example:

```
public ActionResult Index(string v1, int i1) {
   return View();
}

public ActionResult OtherAction(string value, int size){
   return RedirectToAction("Index", // here need some adjustements or another trick);
}
```

Sorry for bad question but I didn't find any related questions here, maybe I don't know to use search :)

Comment: [here's an answer:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Redirect To Action - Need To Pass Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363842/asp-net-mvc-redirect-to-action-need-to-pass-data)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use one of the [overloads of RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460311%28v=vs.108%29.aspx#Y0) which takes a RouteValues object, e.g.

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Controller", new {v1 = "Hello", i1 = 123});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new {v1 = value1,i1=value2} );
```