# Sharing model objects between controller actions in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have two actions in a controller. One that displays a  form  for file upload and another one that displays the results of the upload.
I have created a POCO  called FileInfo i.e

```
public class FileInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Length { get; set; }
        public string FileType { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    }
```

When I submit the form, the Upload action creates and populates  the FileInfo object and then redirects to the second action  called results. I want to be able to use the same file info object in the results action.

I am able to get around this using TemPData[], but it is limited since it only holds object data  for a single request. I presume there must be a better way to share abjects between controller actions.Any help is appreciated!

// Upload Action

```
 List<FileInfo> fileInfo= new List<FileInfo>();
//populate  the fileInfo object using fi.Add()

if ((status.ToString() == "OK"))
             {
                 TempData["Info"] = fileInfo;
                 return RedirectToAction("Results");

             }
             else
             {
                 return RedirectToAction("Index");
             }
```

//Results action.

```
public ActionResult Results()
        {
            List<FileInfo> fi = TempData["Info"] as List<FileInfo>;
            if (fi != null)
            {
                return View(fi);
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Index");
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are storing an instance of `FileInfo` in `TempData`, but trying to retrieve it as `List<FileInfo>`. You will alwasy get `null`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363842/asp-net-mvc-redirect-to-action-need-to-pass-data

Comment: Hi Igor, I have edited the code. I Instantiate the fileInfo object in the upload action, pass it into TempData and then use TempData in the results action. This works but I'm wondering if  there is a better way around it .

Comment: Why are you doing `status.ToString() == "OK"`? I'm guessing `status` is an `enum` so you would be better off doing `status == Status.OK`

Comment: Thanks Trevor! I'm checking `HttpStatusCode` I just realised that I can do it like this: `status == HttpStatusCode.OK`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need something to stick around longer then one subsequent request, you will have to put it in `Session` or in persistent storage (e.g. database).