# Mvc Passing data "RedirectToAction" without using Temp data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tempdata

How to pass model data while redirecting to another action without using TemptData, as given in the example. 
Is there an alternate way to pass EmployeeViewModel from "AddEmployee" action to "Preview" action without using TempData/ Session?

```
public ActionResult AddEmployee(EmployeeViewModel employeeViewModel)
{
  TempData["employee"] = employeeViewModel;
  return this.RedirectToAction("Preview");
}

public ActionResult Preview()
{
  var model = TempData["employee"] as EmployeeViewModel;
  return this.View("Preview", employeeViewModel);
}
```

Comment: Did you google? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363842/asp-net-mvc-redirect-to-action-need-to-pass-data

Comment: L-Three I need to pass the entire Model instead of string. Model has many properties including Collections, Enum values etc.,

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { exception = EmployeeViewModel});
```