# Server side validation of form in partial with different model using Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

View

```
@model List<Dal.IAdministrator>

@Html.Partial("PartialCreateAdmin", new ViewModels.AdministratorCreateModel())
```

Partial

```
@model ViewModels.AdministratorCreateModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Insert", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
{
    <fieldset>
        <br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AccountName, new { placeholder = "Enter the account name here" })
        @if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            <p style="color: darkblue;"> @ViewData.ModelState["AccountName"].Errors[0].ErrorMessage </p> 
        }
    </fieldset>
    <br />

    <input type='Submit' value='Create' />
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Insert(AdministratorCreateModel vm)
    {
       // ...
        if(!accountNameExists)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("AccountName", "Account name does not exist, please try again!");
            return PartialView("PartialCreateAdmin", vm);
        }
        // ...
    }
```

Currently If the validation fails, it returns to the partial, but I want to return the view, with the message along the form?
How can I do this?

Comment: Can you trying `RedirectToAction`? `return PartialView` just returning partial view, you may create another action method returning view to display validation messages.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto yes, but how do I set the ModelState using RedirectToAction?

Comment: IMO `ModelState` can't be accessed directly using `RedirectToAction`, however you can use `Session` property to set the message and return it into target view after redirection using viewmodel.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto `...
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
       TempData["ViewData"] = ViewData;

   RedirectToAction( "Index" );
}

 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     if (TempData["ViewData"] != null)
     {
         ViewData = (ViewDataDictionary)TempData["ViewData"];
     }

     ...
 }`

Comment: Something like this may work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363842/redirect-to-action-and-need-to-pass-data, due to POST-redirect-GET request sequence.