# How do I pass data between two controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

In my specific example, I need to pass an error received on one controller to another controller where it will be display.  Here is a test case I set up.  I've tried TempData, ViewData and Session.  One other thing I noticed is that maybe it's the way I'm redirecting.  When I put a breakpoint on the receiving controller if I just go to it I hit the breakpoint, but on the redirect it never hits.

Sending Controller Action

```
public ActionResult New()
    {
        Session["Notice"] = "There was an error";
        Session["NoticeClass"] = "error";
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Then here's the receiving controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Handle action

        return View();
    }
```

Then a partial view renders out any errors or notices found

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>
<%
    string Message = "";
    string Class = "hidden";
    if (ViewData["Notice"] != null && ViewData["Notice"] != "")
    {
        Message = (string)ViewData["Notice"];
        Class = (string)ViewData["NoticeClass"];
    }
    if (Session["Notice"] != null && Session["Notice"] != "")
    {
        Message = (string)Session["Notice"];
        Class = (string)Session["NoticeClass"];
        Session["Notice"] = null;
    }

    Response.Write("<div class=\"" + Class + "\" id=\"error_div\"><span id=\"error_span\">" + Message + "</span></div>");
%>
```

Comment: What I've found is that I can set the TempData, Session or ViewData on the receiving controller just fine, but when I set the value of any three of those, then do the redirecttoaction the value appears to be lost every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently there's something specific about redirecting to the root of the site.  When I changed the redirect away from /home/index to another action it worked fine.  It was only when I redirected to that one that my values disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

> UPDATE :  Firstly, Sorry but i still
>   cant get a clear picture - assuming
>   you want to get the data in one
>   controller action pass it to another
>   controller's action and then render
>   this in a partial view. You can use
>   Sessions to get the values on the
>   other controller just in a way you
>   stored it....but tempdata i think might also work in your case..then for redirection -

```
return RedirectToAction("Action","Controller",routevalues)
```

> I think you should read about tempdata
>   and viewdata more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173159/difference-between-viewdata-and-tempdata) and dont
>   use ViewData unless you have assigned
>   it some value which I can't see in your
>   code and you are still using it.

Tempdata stores value per request....so a new request means it will lose values.Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936/how-to-redirecttoaction-in-asp-net-mvc-without-losing-request-data) if you are looking to pass values using tempdata.

So, in your case if you are only looking to pass a string do something like this -

```
    public ActionResult New()
    {
        string str = "There was an error";
        return RedirectToAction("Index",str);
    }
    public ActionResult Index(string str)
    {
        Response.Write(str);
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: I actually write it out and format it in a partial view that's used in the master page.  It looks for errors and displays them.

Comment: Also I'm actually passing two pieces of data. Also, I'm not just passing to a different action, I'm passing to a completely different controller.

Comment: if you are passing data between controllers- I think you may want to use Sessions. Post more clearly what you want to achieve..have a look at this simple example - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711.aspx

Comment: Updated the issue with addition info.

Comment: If I'm setting the error on the same page I'm doing the action I use ViewData, if I'm setting it on another controller, then redirecting it, I use Session.  That's why I check for both.