# How to redirect to correct controller action in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post, get

Ok so i have a snippet which is supposed to redirect to a controller's action.

```
return RedirectToAction("add");
```

Now the problem is that `add` action is overloaded. One which gets called when the HTTPrequest is of `GET` type and the other when the request is of `POST` type. Is there anyway that i can select to which action does the statement redirect ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) returns a 302 (moved) response to your client's browser. `GET` is the only method you'll get out that.

If you were asking because you WANT to invoke your POST/add action, this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936/how-to-redirecttoaction-in-asp-net-mvc-without-losing-request-data) might help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult add()
{
    ...
}

[ActionName("add")]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult add_post()
{
    ...
}
```

This way you can POST and GET to add and in the controller you call add or add_post